# What is the most concise way to initialize a Ruby array with at least one default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby, I have an object that has an array. I want to iterate over the values in the array, but I need there to be at least one item in the array. I know I could do something like this:

```
if object.initial_array.empty?
  object.initial_array << "foo"
end
object.initial_array.each do ...
```

But I'd like to be able to do this in one line. What is the most concise way of enumerating an array and specify a default value if empty?

Comment: Where does the empty array in your object come from in the first place, i.e. where do you actually _initialize_ `initial_array` in your code / class?

Comment: To Stefan's point: if your array requires there to be at least one item, and someone hands you an array with no item, then that someone has a bug and needs to fix it. In other words, the "most Ruby way" is to fix the bug at the place where the empty array gets created, not try to deal with an empty array after the fact that should never be empty in the first place.

Comment: That's a good point. Probably a way to ensure the array starts as nil somewhere. And that might be easier to initialize as an array with a default value when nil, rather then trying to add a default value to an empty array.

Comment: _"Probably a way to ensure the array starts as nil somewhere"_ – that's actually the default in Ruby. Right now, `initial_array` seems to be set to an empty array somewhere. Change that to a single-element array containing your default value and your all set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your `initial_array` method have the default, like:

```rb
  attr_accessor :initial_array

  def initial_array
    @initial_array.presence || @initial_array = %w[foo]
  end
```

Comment: That's certainly an option, and I appreciate the answer, even though that's not what I was looking for originally.

Comment: Well, that one line is ALSO the most concise way to initialize an array with a single element.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realize `.presence` would return `nil` for an empty array. I thought it would continue to return the empty array. This is a Rails-specific solution, correct? That's fine, but thought it should be noted.

Comment: Yes, you tagged your question `ruby-on-rails`, that's the context I answered this in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
object.initial_array.tap {|a| a.empty? && a.push("foo") }.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

Or (thanks to [smathy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152786/smathy)), here's a Rails-specific solution:

```
(object.initial_array.presence || ["foo"]).each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

Comment: I mean if you're open to that ugliness then just: `( object.initial_array.presence || object.initial_array << "foo" ).each ...`

Comment: ...but using the method is still much better.

Answer (score 0):

The common Ruby idiom seems to be:

```
object.initial_array ||= ['foo'] 
object.initial_array.each { |item| puts item }
```

while the second line could also be written as

```
object.initial_array.each { puts _1 }     # or
object.initial_array.each(&method(:puts))
```

in newer versions of Ruby.

And although I would usually avoid a one-liner in this case, because I think it is harder to read and to understand, it easily be transformed into one line:

```
(object.initial_array ||= ['foo']).each { |item| puts item }
```

Comment: That only works if `initial_array` is `nil` (or `false`) thought. The OP’s code has `initial_array.empty?` which implies that it is `[]`.

Comment: Not just the `empty?` check, but OP's use of the concat `<<` would fail on `nil`.